# How to apply unlimitedStorage permission to a <webview> component inside a Chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

We are building a Chrome app that is basically a webview displaying one of our website. We've set the "**unlimitedStorage**" permission as described here : https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#unlimited

When we log the available size inside the Chrome app, it displays the whole disk size, but inside the webview no matter what we do we are stuck with the default 600MB.

This web app stores a lot of video in indexedDB so we need to be able to use as much disk size as possible: how can we allow **unlimitedStorage** for the website inside the webview ?

Comment: After some talks with Google, it's actually not possible today to apply the unlimited storage permission to the webview component. We ended up having the Chrome app be the download manager, and the webview controlling the download manager using `postMessage` communication